# scanf using space as a end of line

Tags: c, scanf

For my summer project I built a cheesy little encryption engine, I wanted to have a feature where the user could enter a string/char series and it would encrypt it right in the terminal but for some reason the program (I think its scanf) is only printing out the first word. It could be the way I determine the end of users input but I believe the problem is scanf and not my code (although I read this and it makes me question myself). Here is the code that is relevent:

```
printf("would you like to [e]ncrypt or [d]ecrypt, or type a word to encrypt\n");
char q[50];

for (int s = 0; s < 50; s++) { //initialize string to '0'
    q[s] = '0';
}

scanf("%s \n", q); //reads input from user
for (int s = 0; s < 50; s++) { //for loop to read every char and encrypt it
    if (q[s] == '0') { //'0' determines the end of line
        break;
    } else {    
        union shifter sh = { 0 }; //uses a union to shift the char to unreadable (relatively) char
        sh.str = q[s];
        sh.i += 5;
        printf("%c", sh.str); //prints out chars one at a time
    }
}

printf("\n"); //new line when done
```

inb4 you guys say that the user can't enter a 0, I know this, as a side question, could I initialize it to an unreadable char by  doing say

```
char = 3;
```

and putting it as a unreadable char (end of test to be exact)

thanks for the help

Comment: Since `scanf()` with `%s` stops at the first white space — blank, tab, newline (etc) — there's no surprise that it only reads the first word.  Use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).  Also, the trailing white space (the blank and newline in `"%s \n"`) is dangerous, especially for interactive input.  See [trailing blank in `scanf()` format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/).

Comment: how do use fgets() to get user input then, as I have read its for files and not user input.

Comment: my program now functions as intended, thank you

Comment: regarding: `q[s] = '0';`  The character '0' is 0x30, not 0x00.  are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: *how do use fgets() to get user input*  very simple.  `if( fgets( q, sizeof( q ), stdin ) ) == NULL ) { perror( "fgets failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }  // implied else fgets successful.  // remove trailing newline:  q[ strcspn( q, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: how the user can enter a 0x00 character:  press and hold <alt> then, on the keypad type 000 then release the <alt> then click 'enter'

Comment: As `q` can only hold 49 characters (plus null terminator), you probably want to use a width specifier when using `scanf`. And check the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score -1):

your `%s` will only match the first string of non-whitespace characters.

i.e. if a person types "hello world\n" it will stop scanning after the pace between "hello" and "world".

You can see that this is spelled out in the docs for scanf: see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

where it says for s that it matches:

> Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first whitespace character found. A terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

You probably don't want that space and newline after it as %s will already terminate after that.

I also would suggest %49s so that you don't read more than that many characters.

Edit: adding more clarity for why the input isn't being read after the first word typed.

Comment: What will discard the rest of what?  Please be more precise.  The `"%s \n"` format will skip leading white space, read an unbounded sequence of non-white-space characters, and then the trailing white space in the format string keeps reading and ignoring white space (including newlines) until it comes across another non-white-space character, which it leaves in the input stream ready for the next input operation.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.